# Azure Table Query Delete Items Not In List for Specified Column

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

If I have an `Azure Table` that looks something like this:

```
PartitionKey | RowKey | Timestamp | InstanceId
```

I have `InstanceId`s `a` and `b`. I would like to delete any items in the table that are not in the listed `InstanceId`s (like `c`). The `InstanceId`s goes across `Partition` boundaries. I know how to do the `Batch` `Delete`. But I'm uncertain how to query for items that are not `a` or `b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `InstanceId` type is string,

```
var query = new TableQuery<EntityType>()
    .Where(
         TableQuery.CombineFilters(
             TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("InstanceId", QueryComparisons.NotEqual, "a"), 
             TableOperators.And,
             TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("InstanceId", QueryComparisons.NotEqual, "b")
    ));

//Or you can build the filter string directly
var query = new TableQuery<EntityType>().Where("(InstanceId ne 'a') and (InstanceId ne 'b')");
```

If it's int, similar operation.

```
var query = new TableQuery<EntityType>()
    .Where(
        TableQuery.CombineFilters(
            TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForInt("InstanceId", QueryComparisons.NotEqual, a), 
            TableOperators.And, 
            TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForInt("InstanceId", QueryComparisons.NotEqual, b)
    ));

//Or build the filter string directly
var query = new TableQuery<EntityType>().Where("(InstanceId ne a) and (InstanceId ne b)");
```

Then get the query result using `ExecuteQuery` you need. An example:

```
var entriesResult = table.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, continuationToken).Result.Results;
```